# How to make express.static middleware ignore get parameter?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a mobile app that loads images via http. I'm using a GET parameter for cache busting. In QA and Production the images are served via S3 and this works fine. But in development I'm serving them directly from my node / express backend with express.static(). But here the get parameter makes static not find the file. Is there a way to tell express.static to ignore GET parameter? I digged around code but could find anything obvious. Ideas?

**+++UPDATE+++**

Code and usage example:

```
//serve assets on the dev server only
if ((process.env.NODE_ENV || 'DEVELOPMENT') == 'DEVELOPMENT') {
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'..','public')));
}
```

This one works:
localhost:3000/assets/avatars/example.png

This one doesn't:
localhost:3000/assets/avatars/example.png?v=2

**+++CLOSED++++**

The mistake actually, as suggested below, had nothing to do with static routing. Sincere apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: Can you show what you have so far, or an example? From what it sounds, I don't think there should be any issue.

Comment: Also - are you sure you always want to invalidate your cache in production? Caches can be there for good reason.

Comment: Which express version do you use? In general the `static` middleware is a small [module](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js), if you can't configure it, you can just copy and modify it according to your needs and then use `myStatic()` instead of `express.static()`.

Comment: I second @Jordonias. Express.static will ignore any GET parameters at the end of a static file. Can you be more specific about the break? Perhaps some filename examples that aren't working?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies and suggestions. I updated my question with a code example.
duncahall: It's a version marker, not a randomized cache buster
Boris: At a last resort I always can just use send file. But I'm trying to figure out if I can use standard components.

Comment: I retract the question. Jordonias and Dan were right. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 3):

Express is running all the route you define one after another, so if you do:

```
app.use('/',express.static('/'))
app.get('/myparamter',function(req,res,next){
    res.send('This Will never be called')

})
```

But if you do:

```
app.get('/myparamter',function(req,res,next){
    res.send('This Will be called if you request /myparmeter')
})

// If not another route matches the URL it will server default static file.
app.use('/',express.static('/'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the setup works fine for all files. Except when I use a get parameter.